# Check if a git branch exists in the local repository with ruby?

Tags: ruby, git, branch

What would be the best way of checking if git branch exists in the local git repository with ruby? My ruby skills are not that good, so would like to know the best way of going about it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with this:

```
# Check if a Branch Exists
def branch_exists(branch)
    branches = run("git branch",false)
    regex = Regexp.new('[\\n\\s\\*]+' + Regexp.escape(branch.to_s) + '\\n')
    result = ((branches =~ regex) ? true : false)
    return result
end
```

Where run is a backtick expression. The reasoning is that the code is to be highly portable and is not allowed any other dependencies. Whereas git is installed in the environment.

Answer (score 5):

There are ruby libraries for accessing git repositories, one being [grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit).

To install use `[sudo] gem install grit`.

```
$ irb
>> require 'grit'
=> true
>> repo = Grit::Repo.new('/path/to/your/repo/')
=> #<Grit::Repo "/path/to/your/repo/.git">
>> repo.branches
=> [#<Grit::Head "master">, #<Grit::Head "some-topic-branch">, ...]
```